# sem_release() failed to release key Identifier removed

Tags: php, semaphore

I want to use php semaphore to prevent deadlock in Laravel connection to db.
I use the below sample code and it works on 80% of time, but in real world application it throws error , sem_release(): failed to release key Identifier removed.

```
$sem_id = sem_get($user_id , 1);
if ($sem_id === false)
{
    return  "Fail to get semaphore";
}
 if (! sem_acquire($sem_id))
{
    sem_remove($sem_id);
    return  "Fail to aquire semaphore $sem_id.\n";
}
if (error) {
    sem_release($sem_id);
    sem_remove($sem_id);
    return 'fail';
}
 if (!sem_release($sem_id))// this line throws error 
    return  "Fail to release $sem_id semaphore.\n";
if (!sem_remove($sem_id))
    return "Fail to remove $sem_id semaphore from SysV.\n";
return 'ok';
```

can any body help me out. Thanks

Comment: Did you find the cause? I am having the same issue :/

Comment: no, I use redis lock mechanism for this usage .